Converting from 19V to 5V DC from a laptop battery charger with 3 wires out
I tried to use an old 19V/4.7Amp DC (old laptop charger, 3 wires from AC) and I found it has 3 wires out (red, black and white) like 3 wires on a (bipolar) DC plug - what are they for?
Measuring voltage I get red/white: 19V red/black:0V white/black:17V
I connected red and white wires (19V) to a 5V/3Amp converter https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0C2KJJNM2?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title&th=1    red to red, white to black
No current output at the end of the tester: https://www.amazon.com/DROK-Multimeter-Multifunctional-Electrical-Capacity/dp/B00J3JSEG6
Why is that?
I made another test with another old laptop charger but with 2 wires out and the final voltage was 5V.
Update 1: @TonyM: My knowledge of this matter is almost 0.  You can find out with a DMM resistance test (not a DMM diode test buzz)
THIS is the tester I have (red wire in the center, black at right.
Anyway no buzz between ground an any of the 3 wires

Update 2: @Vir: As far as I recall it was a replacement charger of an original Toshiba


You don't say what mains plug you have on it: 2-pin or 3-pin (including earth). Please edit you question to add this. If the latter, the third wire may be an earth connection. Laptop chargers often earth their DC GND output. You can find out with a DMM resistance test (not a DMM diode test buzz) and also post that result.

Who is the manufacturer of the power brick?

Thanks for editing the new info into the question and a very warm welcome to the site :-) A Digital Multimeter (DMM) usually has a resistance measurement as well as a diode test that gets used as a continuity beep test. A low resistance measurement below 2 ohms is a better indicator of a good connection than the diode test. Anyway, you've found that it's not a mains ground wire.

The 3rd wire is for remote plug voltage sensing to null out flexible lossy cable voltage drop.
If you attenuate the feedback wire from the output you can raise the output voltage. But to lower the voltage you have to change an internal resistor.
The difference among various universal chargers was the designer's choice of resistors wired internally for the White Remote Sense Wire.
Blk is -ve and RED/WHITE must be tied together to regulate 19.x V properly. Then any DCDC 5V regulator may be used. From a surplus PC power supply to an EBAY board for $1 

No idea what are you talking about, sorry :)
Is it possible to get 5V 3Amp at the end without opening the battery charger?

Yes .Connect R/W wire together always and Blk=0V to a 5V Buck regulator with adequate heatsink/ current rating

I already have this converter with the USB socket https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C2KJJNM2 Thanks!
